# Compiling UWP in Unity 2017.3.0f3 fails with NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

I'm trying to compile my project to UWP in Unity 2017.3.0f3. Project works fine in editor, but when trying to compile a build, I get the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.<GetAllScriptAssembliesForLanguage`1>m__8[CSharpLanguage] (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly a) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:899)
System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator1D`1[UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly].MoveNext ()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:128)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:65)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[ScriptAssembly] (IEnumerable`1 source)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.GetAllScriptAssembliesForLanguage[CSharpLanguage] () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:899)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.GetScriptAssemblyForLanguage[CSharpLanguage] (System.String assemblyNameOrPath) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:906)
UnityEditor.WSA.MetroCompilationExtension.GetCsCompiler (Boolean buildingForEditor, System.String assemblyName) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/MetroCompilationExtension.cs:22)
UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CSharpLanguage.GetCSharpCompiler (BuildTarget targetPlatform, Boolean buildingForEditor, System.String assemblyName) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/Compilers/CSharpLanguage.cs:31)
UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CSharpLanguage.CreateCompiler (MonoIsland island, Boolean buildingForEditor, BuildTarget targetPlatform, Boolean runUpdater) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/Compilers/CSharpLanguage.cs:36)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilers.CreateCompilerInstance (MonoIsland island, Boolean buildingForEditor, BuildTarget targetPlatform, Boolean runUpdater) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilers.cs:133)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTask.QueuePendingAssemblies () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/CompilationTask.cs:186)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTask.Poll () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/CompilationTask.cs:137)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScripts (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssemblySettings scriptAssemblySettings, System.String tempBuildDirectory, EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, .TargetAssembly[]& notCompiledTargetAssemblies) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:706)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScripts (EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, BuildTarget platform) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:584)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface+<CompileScripts>c__AnonStorey2.<>m__0 () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilationInterface.cs:177)
UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface.EmitExceptionAsError[Boolean] (System.Func`1 func, Boolean returnValue) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilationInterface.cs:75)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I've installed all the recommended VS 2017 packages and some extra, but I can't figure out what is missing. The first line includes the word "CSharpLanguage" so I make that it has something to do with the CSharp, compiler perhaps?

What does this mean, am I missing some package in VS 2017? If yes, which one? Or is this because of something else?

Comment: Unless something changed there, Unity targets the Mono Framework. UWP however requires .NET Core as target framework. And last I heard, no UWP/WPF support was planned for Mono. So what you are trying might be about as possible as compiling any UWP app agaisnt Mono as target framework,

Comment: I'm trying to follow these instructions. As I understand, Unity builds something called "solution" which Visual Studio then compiles into the UWP app so maybe this is what you mean? However, I can't get the UWP solution to compile on this page: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/exporting_and_building_a_unity_visual_studio_solution